# which one is more correct $[0,\infty)$ or $[0, \infty]?$

Tags: real-analysis, notation

I have seen this interval $[0,\infty)$ and $[0, \infty]$ in many books.

Here I'm confused about which one is correct.

My thinking : Infinity is not particular value like $0$ or $1$ etc  so I think $[0,\infty)$ is correct
but I have seen many authors used $[0, \infty]$ in their books.

So here I'm getting confusion

that which one is more correct  $[0,\infty)$ or  $[0, \infty]$?

Comment: Depends on the context. If you want to consider intervals of the real numbers then $[0,\infty)$ is correct $[0,\infty]$ is not. However, often times (in particular in measure theory) you want to consider functions into the extended real numbers. In that case $[0,\infty]$ is also well defined, but the two are still not the same

Comment: Those are different intervals: $[0, \infty] = [0, \infty) \cup \{ \infty \}$.

Comment: Thanks u @G.Chiusole

Comment: i think ur statement is not correct @Ramanujan $[0,\infty) \cap  \{\infty\} =\emptyset$  but $[0,\infty]$ is connected

Comment: I'd like to know, jasmine, where you've seen $[0,\infty]$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson  **Rudin Book**

Comment: Rudin has written many books. What was the context? Can you give the full sentence?

Comment: see page no$ . 17$@GerryMyerson  **ETH Zurich book**   Pdf link:https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/measure.pdf

Comment: @Ramanujan is right. Just like $[a,b]=[a,b)\cup\{b\}$ for any $a<b$, the same is true for the intervals whose boundary is $\infty$. That doesn't have anything to do with connectedness, since singleton sets aren't open. Connectedness only prevents the set from being a disjoint union of *open* sets.

Comment: @jasmine Well of course in the measure theory text they use $[0, \infty]$, because they want $\infty$ to be in the image space of their functions...

Comment: OK, so, it's as @G.Chiusole wrote in the first comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\infty$ is a possible value, use $[0,\infty]$.

If the value must be a real number, but could be arbitrarily large, use $[0,\infty)$. This is the normal case.

An example of the former might be that for any nonempty subset $A\subset \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$, you can define $\sup(A)\in[0,\infty]$, but for example $\sup(\mathbb N)=\infty$.

On the other hand, if you have a finite set $A$ then its maximum is a real number, so $\max(A)\in[0,\infty)$.